# Why did Culverton give the original page and other info?

Tags: sherlock

Referring to the closing scene of Sherlock S04E02 *The Lying Detective*:

The final scene reveals that the Big Bad gave his daughter's original note page and various details to another character.

> Culverton gave me Faith's original note.
>  A mutual friend put us in touch.
>  Did Sherlock ever tell you about the note?
> I added some deductions for Sherlock. He was quite good. But... he didn't get the big one.

(Found transcript at [this link](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=30473))

By doing so, he set up the caper in which he was caught himself. Why would he do this? I don’t get it.

Comment: @BCdotWEB http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=30473

Comment: Hmm I double-checked the [help page](http://movies.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) but the spoiler syntax is not working. The “!” shows up literally instead.

Comment: You are assuming that Culverton gave the page willingly. Since Moriarty may be involved in the game, he may have been forced to give it. We'll know more next week I guess.

Comment: I don't think Moriarty was involved. The note had been written 3 years ago... Moriarty was dead by then, according to the show's timeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S04E03 'The Final Problem' revealed that the person who obtained the note is a master manipulator of human emotions and will, able to subvert a person's agenda and purpose with her own, after only a short meeting.

> Everyone we sent in there, it's hard to describe, it's... it's like she... recruited them... enslaved them.

It is therefore explicable that Smith would have been entreated to hand over the document successfully, despite there being no advantage to him in doing so.

Answer (score 4):

Culverton thought of himself as unattainable and cleverer than other serial killers. I think he kept his daughter's note so he may be tracked down by Sherlock, initialising an exciting hunt.

He may have not thought about Sherlock at the beginning because the meeting took place 3 years ago if I recall correctly, and at that time, Sherlock was just beginning to be famous as a detective. The "mutual friend"

> (who I suspect is Moriarty)

would then suggest Culverton to chase down Sherlock, using Faith's note as a bait.

Comment: Someone had to fake the provonance of the note (kept in book, then small kitchen, etc.) as well.

Comment: Got point @JDługosz. I can't really guess how long they've planned this scheme, but it must be long enough so the note has all the properties Sherlock deduced.